# Simulate pressed shortcut

Tags: c++, python, qt, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts

Sorry that I have to describe the functionality in such a roundabout manner, but I've no idea how to best implement the wanted functionality*

I have a simple program that puts some data into the clipboard when a global hotkey is pressed. The usual use case for the user is then to directly paste that text into a textfield in Photoshop. I.e. - assuming `ctrl-x` invokes the global hotkey - they're constantly doing `ctrl-x ctrl-v`. Clearly that's bad design.

So what's the simplest way to basically simulate the `ctrl-v` event so that Photoshop will paste the text directly without an additional keypress?

As the `winapi` tag implies I don't care about Macs here. Has to work under Win 7, compatibility with XP/Vista would be a definite plus. Rest of the script is written in Python3 with PyQt4, but I can write some c extension if necessary too.

PS: Everyone who has a better idea wrt the title is more than welcome to improve it.

*And I want to avoid the trap of implementing the simple halve of a problem and then asking for something impossible.

Comment: You could think of your problem as replaying a keyboard macro. You could try sniffing around the source of [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), the Windows keyboard macro recorder, to see how they simulate keypresses.

Comment: @Li Seems like exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! Let's see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Glad to help. If you figure it out, do post an answer back here so we don't have to re-figure it out in the future. ;)

Comment: @Li Planning on that. Now I just have to find the courage to look at win32 code - that API really didn't get more beautiful over the years ;)

Comment: You can use `SendInput` for this, but it's a one-liner in AHK.

Comment: @Voo: And that's the truth. Have you considered just using AHK itself? The scripting language is a bit ugly (reminiscent of BASIC or VB), but it's certainly "effective". If you need more power, I believe the scripting language allows calls to external scripts where you can do your heavy lifting.

Comment: @Li Doable, but it's an additional dependency and I'd have to figure out how to call it from python, etc. I keep it in mind, but for such a simple problem it should be simpler to figure out the win32 API I think.

Comment: @chris You should post that as an answer!

Comment: Do it the other way around; call Python from AHK? If your use case is "custom keyboard shortcuts", that's what AHK was **made** for. Also, "*It should be simpler to figure out the Win32 API*" - consider the sanity of your last statement. :P

Comment: Actually, can you elaborate a bit more about what data gets put on the clipboard? Is it static data, or generated each time? How complex is the generation step?

Comment: Indeed. I believe something like pressing `ctrl-F` to do `ctrl-X` would be along the lines of: `^F::^X` in AHK. I don't use it often, but it's really about that simple.

Comment: @Li A GUI, dynamic data and a really simple LL1 parser. If I ever have to do something more complicated I'll look at AHK, but for now the simpler solution was to use the C code - that way I didn't have to change the rest of the program structure (and c code from cpython is trivially simple with a bit of experience)

Comment: You don't even need to drop into C for this. [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) wraps the C `win32` API pretty closely (all the function call signatures are the same.) It's like your own piece of personal hell, inside Python! :)

Comment: @Li-aungYip, if you have an example, feel free to post. Pure python would be a better solution than importing C.

Comment: @Li Yeah `ctypes` and `pywin32` work fine there too. Actually that's just what I'm planning to write right now - wanted to keep the comment short.

Comment: @chris: I'm only aware of their existence - never used them. Being a Linux user has its advantages. :) That said, your C example should map closely onto `pywin32` API calls - probably don't even need to change the function names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SendInput()`. I didn't test this, but it should work:

```
INPUT ctrlV [4];
ZeroMemory(ctrlv, sizeof ctrlV);

ctrlV [0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ctrlV [0].ki.wVk = VK_LCONTROL;

ctrlV [1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ctrlV [1].ki.wVk = 'V'; //assuming ASCII

ctrlV [2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ctrlV [2].ki.wVk = 'V'; //assuming ASCII
ctrlV [2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

ctrlV [3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ctrlV [3].ki.wVk = VK_LCONTROL;
ctrlV [3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput (4, ctrlV, sizeof (INPUT));
```

Comment: Ah, the glory of Win32. Look at how SIMPLE that is! :)

Comment: @Li Yeah, they really tried to make the API as simple as possible ;) Still works nicely.

Comment: I think the main thing is that it was written in C, and has the purpose of covering all bases. Of course they have been making things easier to use with managed code such as MFC. This function is one of the prime candidates for a wrapper: `Input::generate ("^X");` would be something I could see. Of course there are tons of variations you could put on it.